# Reputation gain for confirmed documentation edits inconsistently treated as part of the cap

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

When you suggest a documentation edit and it has been reviewed, you are given +2 reputation when the change has been approved.

This reputation change was [confirmed to not count towards the daily reputation cap or be subject to the 1000 all-time suggested edit cap yet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31844195#31844195).

However, any such +2 reputation you gain *before* you hit the daily reputation cap *does* count towards the cap, and any you get after *don't*. Today, I had one such event before I hit the cap, and one after (so far, see the [reputation log for 2016-07-24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation&sort=time)).

Not visible in the log is one downvoted answer, costing me -1. So by the time I reached 236 points just before 13:45, I had 3 accepts (uncapped, 45 points), 190 points from answer and documentation upvotes (capped), 2 points from a *doc change* for *Generators ("yield")* (should have been uncapped), and -1 point for a downvote. That's 189 points towards the cap, and 47 points not capped. I then received one more upvote at 13:45:34, which was cut at +9, showing that the reputation calculation *included* the +2 for the doc change towards the cap.

All answer upvotes after that point are fully capped to +0, and answer accepts +15 and the other doc change +2 (*Introduction to Python*) have not been capped. The `/reputation` audit page also capped the +2 points, so this isn't an optimisation error.

Please either make the +2 doc change vote fully uncapped like answer accepts, or make it properly capped, like answer votes.

(This is a separate issue from perhaps capping these votes at a lifetime +1000 rep like suggested edits are).

Comment: Or (c) make it have a global cap just like suggested edits.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: at which point it still would need to be handled consistently. :-)

Comment: Well, I meant "just the global cap", like suggested edits. As I understand, suggested edits don't count in the daily rep cap either, they are independently subject to the global 1k cap. I can imagine a similar feature for doc edits.

Comment: This bug disappeared ages ago, presumably fixed as a side effect of further doc rep work.